# Does the zero product property hold for orthogonal projections on Hilbert spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have two orthogonal projections $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ on a Hilbert space H, where $P_{1} \neq 0$, $P_{2} \neq 0$, $P_{1} \neq P_{2}$, and I define $P = \lambda_{1}P_{1} + \lambda_{2}P_{2}$. I am currently trying to prove that if ran$P_{1}$ $\perp$ ran$P_{2}$, then $PP^{*} = P^{*}P$. I end up with $P_{1}P_{2} = 0$ and $P_{2}P_{1} = 0$. If this is correct, then the equality follows. Am I violating the assumption that $P_{1} \neq 0$, $P_{2} \neq 0$ ? Any responses would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, if ${\rm ran}\,P_1\perp{\rm ran}\,P_2$ then $P_1P_2v=0$ for all $v$ since $P_2v\in{\rm ran}\,P_2\perp{\rm ran}\,P_1$ and $P_1$ is an orthogonal projection, so $({\rm ran}\,P_1)^\perp\subseteq \ker P_1$.
Similarly $P_2P_1=0$ also follows.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thank you very much, I appreciate your response!